# Is it correct to translate *dexiolaboi* as 'spearmen' in Acts 23:23?

Tags: greek, acts

There is no dispute about the Greek noun δεξιολαβος *dexiolaboi* in Acts 23:23, and all translations I have access to have rendered it as 'spearmen'.

A query only arises due to the number of them, because if they are spearmen, there seems to be an inordinate number of them, as the text reads:

> "And he called unto him two centurions saying, Make ready two hundred
> soldiers to go to Caesarea, and horsemen threescore and ten, and
> spearmen two hundred at the third hour of the night." *The
> Englishman's Greek New Testament* by Robert Estienne, 1896 edition
> (originally published 1624)

It appears that 'spearmen' has been retained in as many English translations as I can lay my hands on. However, a comment in the N.I.V. gives rise to this question as it says regarding 'spearmen' "The meaning of the Greek for this word is uncertain. The Greek is an obscure word and could perhaps be translated 'additional mounts and pack animals'."

I learned this from a commentary:

> "The detachment of two hundred soldiers, seventy horsemen and two
> hundred spearmen certainly sounds like an extraordinary
> over-provision, representing about half the garrison. Were [they]
> really necessary for the security of a single prisoner [Paul]?
> ...*dexiolaboi* occurs nowhere else in biblical or contemporary Greek
> literature. Kirsopp and Lake guessed that it means 'led horses', which
> would include both substitute mounts for the long overnight journey of
> nearly forty miles, and pack horses too." *The Message of Acts*, John
> Stott, p.355, IVP, 2000 reprint

In the last 23 years, has there been any further development regarding this obscure Greek word that only crops up once, or **does 'spearmen' remain the correct translation?**

Comment: "Dexiolaboi" is a sick name for a rapper, not gonna lie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most lexicons (eg, BDAG, Thayer, NAS, Strongs, Newman, Souter, Friberg et al, etc) honestly admit that δεξιόλαβος occurring in Acts 23;23 is very rare word of uncertain meaning.  What can be said is that it is composed of two very common words:

- δεξιός = right or right hand
- λαμβάνω = to hold or take hold of

Thus, δεξιόλαβος might mean any of the following (all from afore-mentioned lexicons):

- (right-handed) spearmen (as per the vulgate).  If this is the case, it may refer to a squadron of pike-men - the equivalent of the "sarissa" in the Macedonian phalanx infantry
- (right-handed) slingers
- soldiers whose duty it was to guard captives bound by a chain on the right hand
- especially capable, ie, "dextrous" soldiers
- general body-guards
- bowmen

A very few MSS have dexiobolous (rather than dexiolabous, see NA28) meaning a soldier h=who throws with the right hand, ie, a slinger. [Note that the two words are the same but have the "l" and "b" interchanged - a simple scribal error, but still informative.]

In any case, I cannot find any reference to "dexiolaboi" referring to animals of any kind.

Now, the commander in Jerusalem had requested quite a significant force to protect Paul consisting of:

- two centurions
- 200 soldiers (hence the 2 centurions)
- 70 horseman
- 200 δεξιολάβοι (dexiolaboi)

The reason for such a huge force is probably a combination of the following:

- the commander appears very sympathetic to Paul as described in the previous verse and took the threat seriously
- the commander was told of a force of 40 men waiting in ambush - there were probably many more helpers as these 40 men had taken a vow of starvation and would have needed reinforcements
- a large ambush consisting a more than 40 men is difficult to repel and the commanded wanted to repel any such threat by intimidation rather than actual battle
- some of the men needed to transferred to Caesarea anyway(???)

Answer (score 3):

"Spearmen" is an excellent translation, if it is in the right context. "Slingers" would be an excellent translation in the right context. And "swordsmen" might be an excellent translation, given the right context.

The problem is a problem of specificity. If I told you I just bought a "gun," you might wonder if I mean a pistol, an assault rifle or a cannon.

The ambiguity I'm describing is because the context doesn't actually dictate what kind of weapon he might have in mind. I think a more careful translation would retain the ambiguity, or establish that the context insists on a particular right-handed weapon.

If you disagree with me, I'll still sleep just fine.

Comment: Happy to agree with you on this one, Ruminator!

Answer (score 2):

As I read your question, there are actually two question:

1. What does the word mean?
2. why are there so many

## The word being used

Interestingly enough, there are actually two words to consider, since there's a variant.  The word that is printed in many editions is “ⲇⲉⲝⲓⲟⲗⲁⲃⲟⲩⲥ” (Acts 23:23 GNT-SI). This means, "those holding with the right hand." The variant reading is “ⲇⲉⲝⲓⲟⲃⲟⲗⲟⲩⲥ” (Acts 23:23 GNT-ALEX) ("Those throwing with the right hand."). If "throwing" is the proper reading, then it's clearly javelin throwing skirmishers that are being intended. Likewise, if the word is referring to "right hand holders," then, most likely, it is referring to either javelin throwers or light infantry since the more-heavily-armed soldiers have already been mentioned in the verse “στρατιώτας” (Πράξεις 23·23 THGNT-T). It is very unlikely that this is referring to horses since that is mentioned in the next verse “κτήνη” (Πράξεις 23·24 THGNT-T).

**Conclusion:** Most likely this is speaking about the skirmishers sent out ahead of a traveling army or contingent.

## The number of soldiers

I don't find any evidence that the number should be doubted. All of the manuscripts handed down to us have the same number of units.  Peterson describes the scenario the best:

> The total company of infantry, cavalry and light-armed troops was
> twelve times larger than the band of forty terrorists! The well-known
> dangers of the route might justify such a large military presence (cf.
> Jos., War 2.228, 540-55; Ant. 20.113), but the main point seems to
> have been the commander’s wish to preserve Paul from any further
> threat from his opponents
>
> <David Peterson, The Acts of the Apostles, Pillar New Testament
> Commentary. Accordance electronic ed. (Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 2009),
> 623.>

Answer (score 2):

This word is not so obscure as the NIV translators/editors might wish to make it appear.  Upon inspection of the word in the interlinear, which told me its roots, I was able to identify their basic meanings without a dictionary, based on my own limited Greek coursework.

There are two roots to the word:

- "dexios" -- meaning "right", i.e. "right hand"  (see e.g. Mark 16:5)
- "lambano" -- meaning "take/receive" (see e.g. John 5:41)

Whomever these people are, the implication is that they are taking/receiving something on their right, or perhaps in their right hand.  The word "spearmen" may or may not be the best translation, but the majority of translations, as noted in the OP, do select this word.

Another word used by at least one translation is "light-armed footmen."

> And having called to *him* certain two of the centurions, he said,
> Prepare two hundred soldiers that they may go as far as Caesarea, and
> seventy horsemen, and two hundred light-armed footmen, for the third
> hour of the night.  (Acts 23:23, Darby)

Hebrew Names Version has it as "armed with spears":

> He called to himself two of the centurions, and said, *Prepare two
> hundred soldiers to go as far as Caesarea, with seventy horsemen, and
> two hundred men armed with spears, at the third hour of the night.*
> (Acts 23:23, HNV)

...though I think this takes some liberties with the Greek grammar.

Weymouth has "light infantry":

> Then, calling to him two of the Captains, he gave his orders. "Get
> ready two hundred men," he said, "to march to Caesarea, with seventy
> cavalry and two hundred light infantry, starting at nine o'clock
> to-night." (Acts 23:23, Weymouth)

In all of these cases, there is no suggestion whatsoever that these "δεξιολάβους/dexiolabous" were *horses* or even *horsemen* of any kind.  Looking up references to this word, I found a possible connection to several other words which might be near equivalents, including peltasts, javelinmen, and (Paeonian) archers.

Consider the following Greek excerpt, with English translation, from a site describing the "δεξιολάβους."

| Greek Text [[LINK TO WEBSITE](https://www.michaelagainstantichrist.gr/-the-right-handed-alexander-the-great)] | English, via Google Translate |
| --- | --- |
| THE RIGHT-HANDED – ALEXANDER THE GREAT Θεσσαλονίκη 30-9-2019 Η σελίδα αυτή έχει σχέση με τους ψιλούς στρατιώτες που μάθαμε ερευνώντας τ’ αρχαία στρατιωτικά σώματα χάριν της μεγάλης έρευνάς μας για τους Δεξιολάβους. Κι επειδή μέσα απ’ αυτή την έρευνα διαβάσαμε για περίφημες μάχες της αρχαιότητας, θεωρήσαμε ενδιαφέρον ν’ αναφερθούμε σε 2 απ’ αυτές ως παράδειγμα, για να τιμήσουμε τους στρατηγούς και αξιωματικούς όλων των εποχών που διέθεταν εκείνα τα προσόντα που αποδείχθηκαν καλά απέναντι στον Θεό. Ποια ήταν αυτά; Θα τα δείτε σύντομα, μιας και η παρούσα σελίδα είναι σχετικά μικρή. Ψιλοί στρατιώτες Είδαμε ποιοι ήταν οι ψιλοί στρατιώτες (μονάδα με ελαφρύ οπλισμό που έφερε επιπλέον του ξίφους 2-3 ελαφριά ακόντια και μπορούσαν να ελίσσονται γύρω απ’ την κύρια παράταξη) στ’ αρχαία στρατεύματα, και περιγράψαμε αναλυτικά ότι μέσα σ’ αυτούς υπήρχαν πάντοτε και ανελλιπώς, τα σώματα των πελταστών και τοξοτών (βλέπε και την σελίδα μας, ΔΕΞΙΟΛΑΒΟΙ – ΠΑΡΑΡΤΗΜΑ ). Είδαμε απ’ τα προηγούμενα, ότι τέτοια ελαφρά σώματα ήταν δυνατόν ν’ αποτελούν και ολόκληρο τον στρατό μιας φυλής, όπως οι Παίονες τοξοφόροι, οι Θράκες πελταστές, και οι Σκύθες που είχαν παράδοση στην τοξοβολία από την ηλικία των 5 ετών. Παρόμοια παράδοση υπήρχε και στην εποχή του Μ. Αλεξάνδρου με τους Αγριάνες πελταστές και τους Κρήτες τοξότες, γι αυτό και ο μεγάλος στρατηλάτης τους ενσωμάτωσε στους ψιλούς στρατιώτες του. Και ας μην ξεχνάμε και τους ιθαγενείς ινδιάνους της Βόρειας Αμερικής, που φημίστηκαν ως φυλές πολεμιστών τέτοιου είδους, όπως οι Σιού και οι Απάτσι που έκαναν μεγάλη ζημιά στους πρώτους αποικιακούς στρατούς της Αμερικής, καθώς οι τελευταίοι ήταν εκπαιδευμένοι με τα ευρωπαϊκά πρότυπα, δηλ. μαθημένοι σε μάχη εκ παρατάξεως και όχι σε ανταρτοπόλεμο. Τέλος, μέσα στους ψιλούς όπως είπαμε, μπορούσαν να υπάρχουν και σφενδονήτες καθώς κι ελαφρύ ιππικό. Μέγας Αλέξανδρος - Η μάχη στον Γρανικό ποταμό Ήταν η πρώτη και μεγάλη νικηφόρα μάχη (334 π.Χ.) που άνοιξε τις πύλες της Μ. Ασίας για τις περαιτέρω νίκες των Μακεδόνων του Μ. Αλέξανδρου εναντίον των Περσών. Ο Αλέξανδρος τοποθέτησε τους Αγριάννες πελταστές με τ’ ακόντια και τους Κρήτες τοξότες, περιφερειακά της κύριας δύναμης της μακεδονικής φάλαγγας, στην οποία προηγούνταν το επίλεκτο σώμα ιππικού των διάσημων Εταίρων, με αρχηγό τον ίδιο τον Αλέξανδρο. Μπροστά στην έφοδο λοιπόν της κύριας αυτής δύναμης του Αλέξανδρου προς τον αντίπαλο, υπήρχε ένα σημαντικό εμπόδιο που αποτελούσε πλεονέκτημα για τους πέρσες και μειονέκτημα για τους μακεδόνες: Το ποτάμι. Έπρεπε λοιπόν οι μακεδόνες να περάσουν τον Γρανικό, και να διασχίσουν την αρκετά υπερυψωμένη και λασπωμένη όχθη ώστε να βρεθούν σε στέρεο και οριζόντιο έδαφος. Όχι λίγα δηλ. μειονεκτήματα. Απ’ την άλλη μεριά οι πέρσες που περίμεναν εκεί, ήταν έτοιμοι να εμποδίσουν τους έλληνες να περάσουν το ποτάμι ή να τους εξουδετερώσουν κατά την άνοδό τους στην όχθη, έχοντας επιπλέον το πλεονέκτημα της ψηλότερης θέσης. Αλλά τα πλεονεκτήματα αυτά δεν αξιοποίησαν όπως έπρεπε οι πέρσες διοικητές και σατράπες που ηγούνταν την περσική δύναμη (ο βασιλιάς Δαρείος βρίσκονταν στην Μεσοποταμία προς συγκέντρωση στρατού). Το έργο εξουδετέρωσης των πρώτων σωμάτων των μακεδόνων που θα περνούσαν τον ποταμό ανέλαβαν περσικές μονάδες ελαφρού ιππικού αντίστοιχου με τους πεζούς πελταστές, οι οποίοι όμως έφεραν μόνο 1 ακόντιο. Όταν λοιπόν το έριξαν αυτό, δεν τους έμενε παρά να κάνουν κάθοδο αναχαίτισης προς τους μακεδόνες που ανέβαιναν την όχθη. Τότε λοιπόν ήταν που κατ’ εντολή του Αλέξανδρου, οι πελταστές και οι τοξότες του με τις αλλεπάλληλες και θανατηφόρες ρίψεις ακοντίων και βελών, κράτησαν σε απόσταση τους πέρσες ιππείς, κι έδωσαν τον χρόνο στον Αλέξανδρο με το κύριο σώμα της μακεδονικής φάλαγγας να περάσει τον ποταμό και ν’ ανέβει την κεκλιμένη όχθη. Τότε πλέον τον λόγο είχε το υπερόπλο του Αλέξανδρου, η περίφημη μακεδονική σάρισα (το δόρυ με το μεγάλο μήκος, (5,5-6 μέτρα) που σάρωνε τους αντίπαλους. | THE RIGHT-HANDED – ALEXANDER THE GREAT Thessaloniki 30-9-2019 This page is related to the small soldiers we learned about by researching ancient military corps for our extensive research on the Dexiolavs. And because through this research we read about famous battles of antiquity, we thought it interesting to refer to 2 of them as an example, to honor the generals and officers of all times who possessed those qualities that proved good against God. What were those? You will see them soon, since this page is relatively small. Small soldiers We have seen who were the light soldiers (a lightly armed unit that carried in addition to the sword 2-3 light javelins and could maneuver around the main line) in the ancient armies, and we described in detail that in them there were always and incessantly, the bodies of the peltasts and archers (see also our page, DEXIOLAVI - APPENDIX). We saw from the previous ones that such light bodies could constitute the entire army of a tribe, such as the Paeonian archers, the Thracian peltasts, and the Scythians who had a tradition of archery from the age of 5. A similar tradition existed in the time of M. Alexander with the Agrian peltasts and the Cretan archers, which is why the great soldier incorporated them into his small soldiers. And let's not forget the native North American Indians, who were famous as warrior tribes such as the Sioux and the Apache who did a lot of damage to America's first colonial armies, as the latter were trained to European standards, i.e. learned in a battle of ranks and not in a guerilla war. Finally, as we said, slingers and light cavalry could also be present among the squires. Alexander the Great - The Battle of Granikos River It was the first and great victorious battle (334 BC) that opened the gates of Asia Minor for the further victories of the Macedonians of M. Alexander against the Persians. Alexander placed the Agrian peltasts with javelins and the Cretan archers, peripheral to the main force of the Macedonian phalanx, which was preceded by the elite cavalry corps of the famous Partners, led by Alexander himself. In front of the attack of this main force of Alexander towards the opponent, there was an important obstacle that was an advantage for the Persians and a disadvantage for the Macedonians: the river. So the Macedonians had to cross the Granikos, and cross the sufficiently elevated and muddy bank to find themselves on solid and level ground. Not a few i.e. disadvantages. On the other hand, the Persians who were waiting there, were ready to prevent the Greeks from crossing the river or to neutralize them during their ascent to the bank, having in addition the advantage of the higher position. But these advantages were not exploited properly by the Persian commanders and satraps who led the Persian force (King Darius was in Mesopotamia to gather an army). The task of neutralizing the first bodies of Macedonians that would cross the river was undertaken by Persian units of light cavalry equivalent to foot peltasts, who, however, carried only 1 javelin. So when they dropped this, they had no choice but to descend to intercept the Macedonians who were coming up the bank. So it was then that, on Alexander's command, his peltasts and archers, with successive and deadly throws of javelins and arrows, kept the Persian horsemen at a distance, and gave Alexander the time with the main body of the Macedonian phalanx to cross the river and to climb the sloping bank. Then Alexander's superweapon, the famous Macedonian sarissa (the spear with a long length, (5.5-6 meters)) that swept through the opponents, was now the reason. |

### Conclusion

The translation of "spearmen" is probably the most accurate, considering the Roman context.  The same Greek word might, for other contexts or armies, be applied to archers, javelinmen, peltasts, etc.  It designates a light-infantry type, one that is not heavily armored.